# Vertical Autoscaling on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

Does GKE supports vertical node auto-scaling?

*For example:*

I have a [GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) with only one [node-pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools) and two nodes that node-pool, in case there is a requirement for more memory or CPU by any pod, I do not want any other nodes / compute instances to be created, is there a way in which the configuration of existing nodes change and extra memory / CPU get added?

Basically, existing instances / nodes get upgraded to become instances with higher configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that Google Cloud does not provide feature you want.

There is no way to add CPU/RAM in current `node pool VMs` as nodes used in [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) are based on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) Virtual Machines and resources are specified before creation. If you would like to change CPU/RAM resources in `node pool`, you need to do it manually as `@Emre Odabaş` pointed. However, all nodes must be recreated with higher resources availability.
To fulfill your needs you can choose which [Machine Type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) you want to use, however you can create [Custom Machine Type](https://cloud.google.com/custom-machine-types).

As workaround you could consider to have 2 `node pools`:

one with regular `node-pool-1` with `e2-medium` (2 vCPU, 4GB Memory)

```
$ gcloud container node-pools create node-pool-1 --machine-type=e2-medium --cluster=cluster-1 --zone=europe-north1-b ---num-nodes=2
```

and `node-pool-2` with `e2-standard-4` (4 vCPU, 16 GB Memory).

```
$ gcloud container node-pools create node-pool-2 --machine-type=e2-standard-4 --cluster=cluster-1 --zone=europe-north1-b --num-nodes=0
```

However, this would work only when you would know that you do not have enough resources and change it manually:

- Regular load: 2 node from `node-pool-1`
- Higher load: 1 node from `node-pool-1` and 1 node from `node-pool-2`
- Full load: 2 nodes form `node-pool-2`

Answer (score 1):

You could manually change node pools with different node types. AFAIK there is no vertical node auto scaler in GKE.